# Xslt : Create a namespace dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt, xmlspy

Following are the nodes  in XML Data

```
<WebServiceUrl>"http://webser.part.site"</WebServiceUrl>
<UserName>nida</UserName>
<Passsword>123</Password>
```

I have passed this node value to Xslt Service now i have this url NODE value in parameter e-g

```
    <xsl:param name="UserName"/>
    <xsl:param name="Password"/>
    <xsl:param name="WebServiceUrl"/>
```

Now i want to create a soapenv:Envelope tag and use this value in it

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="$WebServiceUrl">
```

So the final outPut which i want from XSLT Code is as :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:web="http://webservice2.partner.insite">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<web:upload>
<web:username>nida</web:username>
<web:password>123</web:password>
</web:upload></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks alot for your help .

This is your code :

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="UserName"/>
 <xsl:param name="Password"/>
  <xsl:param name="WebServiceUrl" select="'some: namespace'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">    
SOAPAction: "urn:upload"
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
 <xsl:text>
 </xsl:text>
  <xsl:element name="{name()}"
      namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:sequence select="namespace::*[not(name()='web')]"/>
  <xsl:namespace name="web" select="$WebServiceUrl"/>
 </xsl:element>
 <xsl:text>
   </xsl:text>
<soapenv:Header/>
   <xsl:text>
   </xsl:text>
<soapenv:Body>
   <xsl:text>
   </xsl:text>
    <web:upload>
   <xsl:text>
   </xsl:text>      
        <web:username><xsl:value-of select="$UserName"/>                </web:username>
    <xsl:text>
   </xsl:text>
                <web:password><xsl:value-of select="$Password"/>           </web:password>
    <xsl:text>
   </xsl:text>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When i try to save this code it thorws an error as starting tag  of this node is missing

```
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please make changes in this what i am doing wrong in this.

Comment: How would the new namespace be generated if there is no string ""webservice2" contained in the parameter `$WebServiceUrl`? This isn't logical.

Comment: Ok we can make $WebServiceUrl value string as i updated .

Comment: My main concern is to pick the Url Value from parameter 
we have option to make WeserviceUrl value like any one of these:
<WebServiceUrl>"http://webser.part.site"</WebServiceUrl> OR
<WebServiceUrl>web="http://webservice2.partner.insite"
</WebServiceUrl> OR
<WebServiceUrl>xmlns:web="http://webservice2.partner.insite"
</WebServiceUrl>

But At the end what i need is this :

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:web="http://webservice2.partner.insite">

Comment: So, what is the problem with my solution? It does exactly that -- creates a namespace dynamically from the namespace-uri provided in a global parameter.

Comment: Please have a look on above code

Comment: With all due respect, it is elementary to reuse the solution from my answer  -- you should be able to do so yourself. Your question has been cfully answered -- if you have other problems, please, ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

**I. This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="pUrl" select="'some: namespace'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:element name="{name()}"
          namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <xsl:sequence select="namespace::*[not(name()='web')]"/>
      <xsl:namespace name="web" select="$pUrl"/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:web="http://webser.part.site"/>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (the 'web' namespace produced from the value of a parameter):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:web="some: namespace"/>
```

---

**II. This XSLT 1.0 transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="pUrl" select="'some: namespace'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vrtfDummy">
     <xsl:element name="web:dummy" namespace="{$pUrl}"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vNS" select="ext:node-set($vrtfDummy)/*/namespace::web"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:element name="{name()}"
          namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='web')]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$vNS"/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (above), again produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="some: namespace"/>
```

Comment: Note also that if you need to generate elements in the dynamically-selected "web" namespaces within the SOAP message body, you will need to do this using xsl:element with a namespace attribute. You can't just rely on using the prefix "web" and having its binding inherited from a parent element: XSLT needs to know the namespace of an element it is creating explicitly.

Comment: @MichaelKay, Yes, the provided XML document has just a top element and nothing else... Or do I understand you at all?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev , soory i could not convery my message clearly , I have following node 
    <WebServiceUrl>http://webser.part.site</WebServiceUrl>

I just want to append the WebServiceUrl value in the Following Node using XSLT

    <soapenv:Envelope     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web=    <xsl:value-of select="$WebServiceUrl"/>>

Comment: @NidaSulheri: Sorry, but I don't understand your last comment. Please, edit the question and specify the exact wanted result (as XML).

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I have updated my question , please help me out and tell me if further clarification is required.