# Dynamic Namespace in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

If for example I have 3 different XMLs with almost the same content:

Fruits.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Food xmlns="http://foodie1">
  <FoodType>Fruit</FoodType>
  <Name>Mango</Name>
</Food>
```

Veggies.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Food xmlns="http://foodie2">
  <FoodType>Vegetables</FoodType>
  <Name>Eggplant</Name>
</Food>
```

Drinks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Food xmlns="http://foodie3">
  <FoodType>Drinks</FoodType>
  <Name>Iced tea</Name>
</Food>
```

Is it possible in XSLT to create another XML that will take in the value of `<FoodType>` then according to the value, will generate the specific Namespace like in Fruits.xml: `xmlns="http://foodie1"`

Answer (score 0):

To set namespaces dynamically at runtime, use  and an attribute value template.

```
<xsl:element name="SomeElement" namespace="{$some_ns}">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:element>
```

See this link

[Xslt : Create a namespace dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795943/xslt-create-a-namespace-dynamically)